# How do I select wood types for a walk in wardrobe?

Tags: wood-selection

I am an amateur at wood working and am taking my time on my first large project, a [walk-in wardrobe](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/are-there-any-non-obvious-specifically-structural-concerns-to-building-a-walk) for some awkward space in my bedroom.

I've went over and over my plans to make sure they are what I want and now it has come time to buy wood.  At a woodworking class I did recently, it was suggested by the lecturer that I use engineered pine for most of the work as it's inexpensive and doesn't have the ugly look of MDF.
After looking around, it doesn't really seem to come in sizes of 620mm (wardrobe depth)x7ft(roof height).

Aside from that, searching for "Engineered Wood" or "Engineered Pine" always comes up with flooring online on Google and it doesn't seem to exist in any other form on timber merchants websites.

Am I using the wrong terminology to search for the suggested wood or am I right in thinking it doesn't really come in those sizes.
Alternatively, is there a better good quality wood that comes in larger sizes?

Comment: Given the commonness, nay ubiquity, of chipboard and MDF installations across nearly all price points — even >30k kitchens can use one or both materials! — I don't think there's any legitimate reason for anyone to look down their noses at the stuff, so you might take that as a personal bias of the lecturer rather than a bit of impartial and well-reasoned advice.

Comment: I just find laminated chipboard horrible stuff and it doesn't last.  I don't mind MDF but if I can geta nice, stained wood grain effect for a small price increase, I'm all over that.  Also means I can do much of my cutting indoors, while with MDF I need to hulk it all up and down quite a small staircase.

Comment: Laminated chipboard or ContiBoard can last, many a bedroom soldiering on with 10-, 20- or 30-year-old stuff in its cupboards. But it is cheap stuff when you come down to it, and once an edge or corner fails it is very obviously nasty-looking cheap stuff it must be said. Edit: if you have any worries about moisture I've read it is well worth paying the small difference for MR-MDM. And apparently it also tends to cut more cleanly too so has multiple plusses, not just the moisture-resistance.

Comment: That's been my experience, a tiny chip is there for good and tends to spread.  I'd rather just avoid that with an upfront cost.  I'm still not convinced on MDF, after seeing how good real wood looks though.

Comment: Yes solid wood is lovely and all but you must remember it's broadly speaking much more prone to warping and expands and contracts much, much more with seasonal moisture variations. These are some of the motivations for the development of board materials in the first place. Only nice-quality solid wood, well seasoned and put together well, is a really solid choice in thin section and most of that wood should be quarter-sawn for stability. Solid wood would be pricey already, QS on top of that would not come with only a small premium :-)